# Import classes and external libaries in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I'm importing a external class in ts from another class.

```
import {client} from '../../'
```

do i need to make an new instance of the var before using it inside another class?  (e.g `let cli = new client()}`) i saw some tutorials and some of them barley talk about this. they just import and use it directly.

hope you can explain.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're importing ..

if it is a `CLASS` ... so : YES .. for example:

```
export class User{

public name:string;
public surname:string;
}
```

then in your other ts file:

```
import { User } from '../../User';

let user= new User();
user.name= 'Fred';
user.surname = 'Scamuzzi';
```

IF you're importing for example an `INTERFACE` .. then NO:

for example

```
import {  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { User } from '../../User';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { // --> it force you to implement the method declared in OnInit interface


ngOnInit(): void { // implemented

        let currentUser = new User();
    }

}
```

And the same for exmplae when you import  a Component in NgModule to declare it .. you just do:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AuthService} from './shared/services/AuthService.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,

        HttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent

    ],
    providers: [

        AuthService

    ],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Hope it helps you ....

Comment: ok, and if i import a namespace, is that the same?  still need to create a new instance of that namespace ? thanks